# mysqli_prepared_query: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've seen similar problems listet here in stackoverflow or google but nothing helps me.
And I don't wanna set the memory_limit to -1, my intention is to really solve the problem in my code.

my code:

```
    function mysqli_prepared_query($link, $sql, $types = false, $params = false) {

    $multiQuery = false;

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
        if (!is_array($params))
            $params = array(array($params));
        elseif (count($params) == count($params,1))
            $params = array($params);
        else
            $multiQuery = true;

        $bindParams = array();
        if ($types) {
            $bindParamsReferences = array();
            $bindParams = array_pad($bindParams,(count($params,1)-count($params))/count($params),"");
            foreach($bindParams as $key => $value)
                $bindParamsReferences[$key] = &$bindParams[$key];
            array_unshift($bindParamsReferences,$types);
            $bindParamsMethod = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param');
            $bindParamsMethod->invokeArgs($stmt,$bindParamsReferences);
        }

        $result = array();
        foreach ($params as $queryKey => $query) {
            foreach ($bindParams as $paramKey => $value)
                $bindParams[$paramKey] = $query[$paramKey];
            $queryResult = array();
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                $stmt0  = substr(strtolower($sql), 0, 6);
                if ($stmt0 == 'insert')
                    return mysqli_insert_id($link);
                elseif ($stmt0 != 'select')
                    return true;

                $resultMetaData = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
                $stmtRow = array();   
                $rowReferences = array();
                while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($resultMetaData))
                    $rowReferences[] = &$stmtRow[$field->name];
                mysqli_free_result($resultMetaData);

                $bindResultMethod = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_result');
                $bindResultMethod->invokeArgs($stmt, $rowReferences);

                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                    $row = array();
                    foreach ($stmtRow as $key => $value)
                        $row[$key] = $value;
                    $queryResult[] = $row;
                }
                mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);

            } else
                $queryResult[] = false;

            $result[$queryKey] = $queryResult;
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } else
        $result = false;

    if ($multiQuery)
        return $result;
    else
        return $result[0];
}
```

error message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2128 bytes) in /mysite/scripts/db.php on line 200
```

thrown error line 200 is:

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
```

error appears when the result is greater than 2450 data rows.

Comment: And what is the average row size?

Comment: it depends on the saved proposals for each user. the range is something like between 300-4000

Comment: So it should be 5M on average if I am not mistaken. It seems either you are wrong on the row size estimation or something is really wrong with your code. Did you try to fetch the same rows without all that fancy stuff, with just regular while loop?

Comment: Thank U "Your Common Sense", i solved it.
I removed all the fancy stuff and build it step by step.